# How to specify project url in Jenkins where project is among other projects in git reporsitory

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

I'm trying to test one of my maven projects in Jenkins. It's in our internal git repository. But that project is not the only one in that repository. It's got many other sibling projects. Now, when I create a job for a particular project that's in Git, how do I make so that when I click Build now, Jenkins builds that project? How do I make Jenkins find the pom file it should use? I haven't been able to figure this out so far. The only thing that comes to mind is maybe our repository structure is wrong and we should have had one dedicated repository for each project. Is that the case?

Here's the structure of the repository

[image]

The project I'm interested in is the one with name "reporting".

Comment: Are those projects within this single repository related to each other? Is this a multi module build? Usually it's best have a git repository per project...Can you give an layout example?

Comment: Added the repository structure, see the edit please